# Unable to connect to localhost after windows 10 upgrade

Tags: windows

I have upgraded to windows 10 from 8.1 yesterday.

After the upgrade I can no longer access localhost which worked fine prior to the upgrade. A message appears on diagnostic which says one or more network protocols are missing.

Running repairs as admin fails not able to repair. I have reset adapters, catalogs, flushed dns, etc. still no luck.

I can connect to the internet OK its just the localhost that is the issue as far as I can see. I have disabled windows firewall confirmed my router port forwarding, etc all are working fine. No Anti Virus running (disabled), Disabled Malware Bytes no luck.

Comment: Specific error messages or log files would help formulate an answer.

Comment: Try this: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_web/missing-network-protocols-help-please/fb17c35c-d4eb-41b8-b966-db5c304c80ed

Comment: Now that you have upgraded the internal key....maybe it is time to do a fresh install from scratch.

Comment: Can you share with us full output of `ping localhost` and `ping 127.0.0.1` commands?

Comment: I installed Windows 10 and none of my Visual Studio projects worked any more. I kept getting the 'unable to connect to localhost' message. I installed the latest Visual Studio Community. Still no joy. I ran it & it hanged there. Then I took your suggestion and did ping localhost and ping 127.0.0.1. Instantly my application web page came on! Strange, but it now works!

Answer (score 13):

There most likely are two possibilities, either the network adapter driver or the hosts file has some problem.
To fix the hosts file issue:

1. Go to `%systemroot%\System32\drivers\etc`
2. Backup the `hosts` file
3. Then open notepad with administrator rights.
4. Navigate to the same folder and open the `hosts` file
5. Make sure the first line after the # lines (comments) is `127.0.0.1 localhost` and the second is `::1 localhost`
6. Then open cmd and run the command `ipconfig /flushdns`
7. Restart the browser or whatever program you are using.

If it still doesn't work try restarting the PC, else it is some other problem.

Comment: This post helped me solve a socket myth. Thanks!

Comment: Sure enough, 5 years after this answer was posted, there it is in ```hosts```, commented out just under *this* comment:  ```# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.```  Nooo... no it is not, apparently, in Win10 Pro 1903.  I  just got the feature update yesterday afternoon and gave up. (Not sure which Win10 it was on before, but I can tell you at least **localhost worked there.**)

Comment: This is the second time it has happened to me after a Windows update. I signed up on SuperUser just to upvote question and answer!

Comment: Just encountered the same problem, commenting here so that someone might benefit. If you are mapping localhost to other domains and you have two lines like these
127.0.0.1 local.whatever.com
AND
::1 local.whatever.com
This duplication causes this error. Try removing the duplicates might work